# Multiple serializations on state server corrupt property value

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, serialization, dependency-injection, state

I have an abnormal serialization/de-serialization behavior in my ASP.NET MVC application.

**Setup and architecture are as follows:**

.Net 3.5, MVC 2, Unity 2.0 for dependency injection, IIS 7. State is stored in ASPNET state process. Application apart from models, views and controllers also contains a number of application specific services and model mappers (for interfacing with existing code). Two of the services have per Session based lifetime, for which I implemented custom `PerSessionLifetimeManager` (as Unity does not have one out of the box). This lifetime manager uses `HttpContext.Current.Session` to store objects. There are fair bit of dependencies between controllers, mappers, services and between services as well.

**Problem:**

One of session lifetime services contains a private boolean field which changes value under some internal logic conditions, however this value changes by outside of my code. After some investigation I found that problem relates to this object being serialized/de-serialized twice every time and values of the field are different during serializations.

**Investigation done so far:**

I have a break points/logging on object constructor and I wrapped field into a property and put breakpoint/logging on setter. Object is definitely constructed only once and there are no calls to change property value except those which should be called. I have made object to implement `ISerializable` and put logging of `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId` and object hash (constructed from all fields of the object). From what I can see if value of the property/field changes object gets serialized twice once with new value and immediately after with original value. Next time object is used it de-serializes in LIFO order, so the original (unchanged) value object is pulled out first and then the changed one. I tried to log a full stack trace for these serialization calls, but it seem to be all .Net internal calls.

**Questions:**

Why is there multiple serializations with different values? How to avoid this?

**Current work around:**

I used Session instead of private field/property and it works fine, however use of session on heavily loaded websites is not the best thing and I am hoping to for some other solution.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried using an object with only a single boolean value? Can you reproduce it like that? If not, can you try this as stripping all the complexity from your problem points you in the right direction most of the times.

Comment: I coudl be that the serialization/deserialization isn't working properly so the bool is getting defaulted. Otherwise, it could be multiple threads doing the same work causing the multiple serialization processes. Or both.

Comment: I originally had just boolean field on the class and problem was there. Unfortunately stripping complexity down did not work as I suspect it is a combination of factors - State Server, Unity, MVC?

Comment: DustinDavis, I am not using bool anymore, it is string. Threading is not an issue here as I was logging thread ID (see "investigation so far" section) and it is same thread which does multiple (de)serializations

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure the value is becoming corrupted or are you simply loosing the value due to the session being purged.   Do you have any other values in the session that disappear at the same time?  I was a bit confused by your "State is stored in ASPNET state process. " statement.   Is your session management set to InProc or are you using a StateServer?   If it is InProc, you definitely will experience loss of session values (especially in shared hosting environments), and should switch to an ASP State Server Service or MSSQL State Server solution.

Comment: No session is not purged, there are a few other objects in Session and they all Ok (or I have not noticed abnormal behavior in them). Session management is set to StateServer. Changing to InProc makes problem go away (no serializations take place), but obviously this solution is not suitable. In general problem is not that objects disappear from session, but objects stored (serialized) multiple times with different values.